# VBA - Open file from a specific folder and do action

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open files from a specific folder and do the actions with my code below.
But when VBA opens the first file, it stops.
Please help me!

```
Sub ExtractData?()
    '
    ' ExtractData? Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
    '
    Dim buf As String
    Dim dlg As FileDialog
    Dim fold_path As String



    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If dlg.Show = False Then Exit Sub

    fold_path = dlg.SelectedItems(1)

    buf = Dir(fold_path & "\*.xlsx")

    Do While buf <> ""

        Workbooks.Open fold_path & "\" & buf


        Sheets("データセット1").Select
        Range("A2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Windows("Workbook.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets("GE").Select
        Cells(Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Workbooks(buf).Close SaveChanges:=False
        buf = Dir()
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: where does it stop ? what line ?

Comment: try `Do While Len(buf)> 0`

Comment: it stops after open the first file.
Btw, thank you for editing the post.

Comment: you code works for me. I commented everything between the open and close lines..... so probably there's  where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not coming from your `Do While buf <> ""` loop, but from what you are trying to achieve inside (copy >> paste between workbooks).

Inside your loop, you have too many `Select`, `Selection` and `Activate`, instead use fully qualifed `Range` and `Cells`.

You can use `With openWB.Worksheets("データセット1")`, and below it nest your range with `.Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Copy`.

**Code**

```
Sub ExtractData①()

' ExtractData? Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'
Dim buf As String
Dim dlg As FileDialog
Dim fold_path As String
Dim openWB As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If dlg.Show = False Then Exit Sub

fold_path = dlg.SelectedItems(1)
buf = Dir(fold_path & "\*.xlsx")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While buf <> ""
    Set openWB = Workbooks.Open(fold_path & "\" & buf)  '<-- set open workbook to object

    With openWB.Worksheets("データセット1") '<-- not sure about this name (I don't have this font)
        ' set the range from A2 to last cell with data in sheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Copy
    End With

    ' if "Workbook.xlsm" is this workbook with the code, could be repalced with ThisWorkbook
    With Workbooks("Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("GE")
        .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                                        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With

    openWB.Close False
    buf = Dir()
Loop

' restore settings
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code but it still has the same problem. It just opens the target file and then stops there, doesn't do the action.

Comment: @Tuan  do you have a worksheet with the name you specified above ? For every workbook in the folder ??

Comment: yes, every files in the folder have the worksheet i specified.
The worksheet is the second sheet in the file, but the macro just stops at the first sheet after opened the workbook

Comment: @Tuan  can u add a breakpoint inside? Put it at the line with With(openWB)... and see where the code stops

Comment: Your code doesn't just stop, it gives you an Error number and message. **A)** Output the error code and error message with `Debug.Print Err & " | " & Error`  **B)** make yourself familiar with the concept of error handling. I add a simple example to my code

Comment: @MartinDreher not for me, and I tested it. Where is it failing ? What did you test ?

Comment: @MartinDreher Didn't have any Error message show up. :(

Comment: @Shai Rado I put breakpoint like you said, but it run to the breakpoint without stopping.

Comment: @Tuan  if it not stopping, when you run in debug, with F8 , what does it do? Does it copy >> paste the first time before exiting the loop ?

Comment: @Shai Rado if i run it in debug, then it run to the end without any problem. :(
Update: I dont know why but it's working now.

Comment: @Tuan when you run it in debug it runs for all files in the folder ? it copies them correctly to your worksheet ?

Comment: @ShaiRado miscommunication on my behalf, i didn't mean **your** code stops. ;) What i wanted to say was: if the OP's code stops like he mentioned, there will be an error number and message, which gives a lead

Comment: @Martin Dreher It really didn't showed any error messages at all. :(

Comment: @ShaiRado yes, it run to the end and correctly copies all data to my worksheet. And after i run it in debug now it run correctly in normal mode as well.

Comment: @Tuan strange, try Restarting Excel, then try to run it a few times, and see if it works withut issues. If it does, feel free to mark as "Asnwer" (click on the **V** next to my answer)

Comment: @ShaiRado it really was strange. I tried to run it a few times to see if any issues occur but i think it run correctly now. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: @Tuan but you gave the "Answer" not to my answer ? Why did u have the other answer the mark ? Out of curiosity

Comment: @Shai Rado my mistake. :). i 've just changed it.

Answer (score 0):

While your code works for me, using `Select`, `Selection` and `Activate` is pretty prone to error, especially when used in loops or when working in several workbooks.

Using nested `With Objects` makes it saver, faster and readable without forcing you to `Dim` and `Set` a ton of object variables. Try this:

```
On Error Goto catch:
try:
With Workbooks.Open(fold_path & "\" & buf)

    With .Sheets("データセット1").Range("A2")
        Range(.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight), .End(xlDown)).Copy
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GE")
        .Cells(Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
finally:            
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

' rest of your code

Exit Sub

catch:
Debug.Print "Err at File " & buf & vbCrLf & Err & vbTab & Error
GoTo finally
```

Addidional notes:

- `.End(...)` will get wrong results if there is an empty cell on the left or top border of your data range.
- above is a simple example of an error handling routine, using pseudo `try, catch, finally`. Make sure you don't create any infinite loops (meaning: only execute bullet-proof code after the `finally` and add `Exit Sub` above the `catch:`
- there are rare cases where the use of `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` makes sense.

  However, in your case it's save to assume that there are simpler, faster and more fail proof options:

  - `Range1.Value = Range2.Value`, which writes the data in one step (therefore it's not simply screwed by user interactions, like `.Copy + .Paste` is
  - Read the data into an `Array` or better a `Recordset`, which allows additional processing, like filtering out empty rows
  - pull data with an `ADO.Connection` and SQL, which, you guessed it, allows even simpler processing and doesnt need the `.Open + .Close` and switching between workbooks

Hope that helps!